# Поле для рисование (графический редактор) java

Tags: java, swing, графика, awt

Пишу графический редактор на java.
Не могу понять, как сделать то поле, на котором все будет происходить.
Понятно, что все используют Graphics, Graphics2D, но я вообще не понимаю, как его включить и куда его приставить в моем коде. 
Пытался делать как у других, но у меня не получалось

Вот код, строчек многовато, но по существу мало:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import static java.awt.Font.MONOSPACED;
import static java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;


public class GraphicsEditor extends JFrame {
    File file; // Our selected file

    BufferedImage f = new BufferedImage(600, 300, TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = f.createGraphics();

    private ActionListener open = new ActionListener() { // Opens a file
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                    "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif", "png");
            chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
            if(JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ==
                    (chooser.showDialog(null, "Open"))) {

                file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            }
        }
    };

    private ActionListener save = new ActionListener() { // Saves a file
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            File file = null;
            int r = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
           /* if(JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ==
                    (chooser.showSaveDialog(null)))*/


        }
    };

   /* Remove the full paths to the icons sometime*/

   ImageIcon pencilIcon = new ImageIcon("D:\\java\\ideaprojects\\graphics editor\\Icons\\Pencil.png");
   ImageIcon eraserIcon = new ImageIcon("D:\\java\\ideaprojects\\graphics editor\\Icons\\Eraser.png");
   ImageIcon textIcon = new ImageIcon("D:\\java\\ideaprojects\\graphics editor\\Icons\\Text.png");
   ImageIcon sizeIcon1 = new ImageIcon("D:\\java\\ideaprojects\\graphics editor\\Icons\\1.png");
   ImageIcon sizeIcon2 = new ImageIcon("D:\\java\\ideaprojects\\graphics editor\\Icons\\2.png");
   ImageIcon sizeIcon3 = new ImageIcon("D:\\java\\ideaprojects\\graphics editor\\Icons\\3.png");
   ImageIcon whiteIcon = new ImageIcon("D:\\java\\ideaprojects\\graphics editor\\Icons\\white.png");
   ImageIcon blackIcon = new ImageIcon("D:\\java\\ideaprojects\\graphics editor\\Icons\\black.png");
   ImageIcon redIcon = new ImageIcon("D:\\java\\ideaprojects\\graphics editor\\Icons\\red.png");
   ImageIcon greenIcon = new ImageIcon("D:\\java\\ideaprojects\\graphics editor\\Icons\\green.png");
   ImageIcon yellowIcon = new ImageIcon("D:\\java\\ideaprojects\\graphics editor\\Icons\\yellow.png");
   ImageIcon blueIcon = new ImageIcon("D:\\java\\ideaprojects\\graphics editor\\Icons\\blue.png");

   JButton pencil = new JButton(pencilIcon);
   JButton eraser = new JButton(eraserIcon);
   JButton text = new JButton(textIcon);
   JButton size1 = new JButton(sizeIcon1);
   JButton size2 = new JButton(sizeIcon2);
   JButton size3 = new JButton(sizeIcon3);
   JButton white = new JButton(whiteIcon);
   JButton black = new JButton(blackIcon);
   JButton red = new JButton(redIcon);
   JButton green = new JButton(greenIcon);
   JButton yellow = new JButton(yellowIcon);
   JButton blue = new JButton(blueIcon);



    private JMenu[] menus = {
            new JMenu("File")/*, new JMenu("Tools"),
            new JMenu("Size")*/
    };

    private JMenuItem[] items = {
            new JMenuItem("Open"), new JMenuItem("Save"),
            new JMenuItem("Save as")/*, new JMenuItem("Pencil"),
            new JMenuItem("Eraser"), new JMenuItem("Text"),
            new JMenuItem("1"), new JMenuItem("2"),
            new JMenuItem("2")*/
    };

    public GraphicsEditor() {
        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            menus[i/3].add(items[i]);

        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        for(JMenu jm : menus)
            mb.add(jm);
        setJMenuBar(mb);

        Dimension colours = new Dimension(15, 15);
        Dimension sizes = new Dimension(20, 20);
        size1.setPreferredSize(sizes);
        size2.setPreferredSize(sizes);
        size3.setPreferredSize(sizes);
        pencil.setPreferredSize(colours);
        eraser.setPreferredSize(colours);
        text.setPreferredSize(colours);
        white.setPreferredSize(colours);
        black.setPreferredSize(colours);
        red.setPreferredSize(colours);
        green.setPreferredSize(colours);
        yellow.setPreferredSize(colours);
        blue.setPreferredSize(colours);


        add(pencil);
        add(eraser);
        add(text);
        add(white);
        add(black);
        add(red);
        add(green);
        add(yellow);
        add(blue);
        add(size1);
        add(size2);
        add(size3);

        g.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        items[0].addActionListener(open);  // open a file
        items[1].addActionListener(save); // save the file

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Swing.go(new GraphicsEditor(), 750, 550);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У JFrame (в данном случае GraphicsEditor) необходимо вызывать метод `setVisible(true)`. Это можно сделать как в конструкторе, так и после создания объекта.

Comment: Да, это все присутствует
В main вызывается функцию go(), и там все это содержится(setVisible, setDefaultCloseOperation и т.д.) 
Дело именно в том, что мне нужно как то установить поле для рисования, там где черкать и тд

Comment: Добавьте объект класса 'Canvas' во фрейм и повесьте на него слушателей, чтобы при нажатии кнопок мыши можно было рисовать, при нажатии клавиш включались кнопки. Если нужен пример - вечером скину.

Comment: http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/16/16/lecture/27125?page=4 - Тут есть пример рисовалки.